# TextViews in ConstraintLayout not wrapping properly despite setting properties

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

For some strange reason, the `TextViews` in my `ConstraintLayout` won't budge to show all text and it appears to go over the screen's boundaries. I already tried using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` but that didn't have any effect in changing the positioning, leading me to think what would happen to the '1C' and '1D' text views when I add longer text in those.

**Current result**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutA"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

                    <!--Constraint 1-->
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutTitle"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ibA"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvA"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ibA"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <!--Constraint 2-->
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivA"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvB"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivA"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivA"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvC"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvD"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivA"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvB"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivD"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ivA"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivA"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivA"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvD"
                        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvD"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivD"

                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvC"
                        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Suraj Vaishnav's suggestion**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no constraint from the right(or end) side, add this `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` to tvA,tvB and so on.

**Update:**

apply both constraints: start and end and set the width 0dp. here are the working properties for tvB:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvB"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
...
```

I guess you can do the same things for tvC & tvD, let me know if you face any issue.